# Java Regex Matching And Hibernate Validators

Tags: regex, forms, spring, pattern-matching, hibernate-validator

I am using Hibernate validators on my form and am running into this problem. The validators are as follows:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Firstname cannot be empty")
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$", message = "First Name can only contain characters.")
private String firstname;
```

If the firstname is empty both @NotEmpty as well as @Pattern are getting triggered.

**Question**

- How do I make @NotEmpty trigger ONLY when the firstname is empty and @Pattern trigger ONLY when it contains illegal characters like '#' or '&'?

Comment: Just a nitpick, you can reduce that regexp to `^\w+$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

Instead of:

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

The `*` should make your regex also match the empty String. So for the case the String is empty only @NotEmpty should be triggered